# Converting a String to json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

The string below I believe is in json format but when I try to
load string into a json variable so I can easily query and extract the data points it errors out.

```
jdata = '<pre>{\n    "askId": "AAABB110-000011",\n    "dateCreated": "2009-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",\n    "dateUpdated": "2021-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",\n    "owners": [\n        {\n            "ownerType": "Service-Level Owner",\n            "VendorId": "000111222"\n        },\n        {\n            "ownerType": "Technical Owner",\n            "CustomerId": "000333444"\n        },\n        {\n            "ownerType": "Business Owner",\n            "ServiceId": "000005556"\n        }\n    ],\n    "createdBy": "SYSTEM",\n    "lastUpdatedBy": "000667778",\n    "applicationName": "Treasury Bank Data",\n    "description": "Process Data",\n    "aliases": [\n        "Treasury Bank Data",\n        "Bank Data",\n        "Bank Reconciliation",\n        "Bank Rec",\n        "SERV-X"\n    ],\n    "billingBusinessSegmentId": 6,\n    "category": {\n        "categoryId": 1,\n        "categoryName": "Application"\n    },\n    "lifecycleStage": {\n        "lifecycleStageId": 3,\n        "lifecycleStageName": "Production"\n    },\n    "acquiredEntity": {\n        "acquiredEntityId": 0,\n        "acquiredEntityName": "Not Applicable"\n    },\n    "enclaveEnvironment": {\n        "enclaveEnvironmentId": 0,\n        "enclaveEnvironmentName": "General Hosting (Internal, Cloud, or Vendor hosted)"\n    },\n    "softwareType": {\n        "softwareTypeId": 7,\n        "softwareTypeName": "Vendor Product"\n    },\n    "infrastructureRequired": false,\n    "uhgHelpdeskRequired": false,\n    "references": [\n        {\n            "referenceType": "disaster-recovery",\n            "referenceValue": "APPX009919"\n        }\n    ]\n}\n</pre>'

jsonData = json.loads(jdata)
```

Once I try to load the data into jsonData variable i get error below.

```
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Is there something wrong with my string not allowing me to load as a json variable?

Comment: That is not JSON.

Comment: That string seems to be the string representation of HTML that will display the JSON.

Comment: Remove the `<pre>` and `</pre>` from it and I think you should be able to load it.

Comment: If you trim of `<pre>` and `</pre>` THEN you have JSON

Comment: That was my first thought to remove the pre and it would be json. I removed it as a replace with ''. Yet after this change it would still fail with TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you strip off the html tags, you get json:

```
import json

jdata = '<pre>{\n    "askId": "AAABB110-000011",\n    "dateCreated": "2009-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",\n    "dateUpdated": "2021-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",\n    "owners": [\n        {\n            "ownerType": "Service-Level Owner",\n            "VendorId": "000111222"\n        },\n        {\n            "ownerType": "Technical Owner",\n            "CustomerId": "000333444"\n        },\n        {\n            "ownerType": "Business Owner",\n            "ServiceId": "000005556"\n        }\n    ],\n    "createdBy": "SYSTEM",\n    "lastUpdatedBy": "000667778",\n    "applicationName": "Treasury Bank Data",\n    "description": "Process Data",\n    "aliases": [\n        "Treasury Bank Data",\n        "Bank Data",\n        "Bank Reconciliation",\n        "Bank Rec",\n        "SERV-X"\n    ],\n    "billingBusinessSegmentId": 6,\n    "category": {\n        "categoryId": 1,\n        "categoryName": "Application"\n    },\n    "lifecycleStage": {\n        "lifecycleStageId": 3,\n        "lifecycleStageName": "Production"\n    },\n    "acquiredEntity": {\n        "acquiredEntityId": 0,\n        "acquiredEntityName": "Not Applicable"\n    },\n    "enclaveEnvironment": {\n        "enclaveEnvironmentId": 0,\n        "enclaveEnvironmentName": "General Hosting (Internal, Cloud, or Vendor hosted)"\n    },\n    "softwareType": {\n        "softwareTypeId": 7,\n        "softwareTypeName": "Vendor Product"\n    },\n    "infrastructureRequired": false,\n    "uhgHelpdeskRequired": false,\n    "references": [\n        {\n            "referenceType": "disaster-recovery",\n            "referenceValue": "APPX009919"\n        }\n    ]\n}\n</pre>'

jsonData = json.loads(jdata.lstrip('<pre>').rstrip('</pre>'))
print(jsonData)
```

Comment: Your command worked the pre tags are gone. I get a differernt error when I try to load data. Here is Error:  TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict

Comment: Terry could it be because this is not wrapped in "[ ]" I tried to concatenate but got error you cant concatenate to dict only string

Comment: The code above works, can you post the code you're trying to run?

Comment: data = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8') ____________________________________________________________________
   soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser') ____________________________________________________________________
jdata = str(soup.find('pre')) ____________________________________________________________________________
json_content = json.loads(jdata.lstrip('<pre>').rstrip('</pre>')) __________________________________________
jsonData = json.loads(json_content) ____________________________________________________________________

Comment: No need to call json.loads() twice.

Comment: Yes That was it

Comment: if you are already using beautifulsoup why don't you just extract the text in `pre`: `soup.find('pre').contents[0]`